# Where is that javascript tool that minifies the js files?

Tags: javascript

I can't find that tool that minifies that javascript.

Its a java based tool.

I thought douglas crawford made it, but can't find it on his site even!

Comment: Has asking questions on SO become a replacement for a simple google search?

Comment: No kidding.  This is a Google question.

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for JSMin?

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of them.

- [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)
- [Online interface to Douglas Crockford's](http://fmarcia.info/jsmin/test.html)

Incidentally, Crockford's tool is the [#2 result on Google for "javascript minify"](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+minify).

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want the actual Douglas **Crockford** one, that's here:
http://javascript.crockford.com/jsmin.html

Otherwise, Google for "js minifier" should find at least a few alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

I would use either [JSMin](http://crockford.com/javascript/jsmin) or [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

Both are good tools.

Answer (score 2):

There's a whole list in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minify). Not only Javascript, but at least 3 for it.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of Mike Hall's [Crunchinator](http://www.brainjar.com/js/crunch/)?